# Hasmorepages property fails

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have created a routine that is intended to print a variable number of lines and/or pages, based on a queue of line information previously stored.  Each page prints fine, but when printing more than one page, two pages overprint.  I can't see my logic error, but there must be one.  A copy of the offending code is follows.  Nextline.newpage is a boolean set to true to force a new page.  In my text example there were six "Newpage" and "hasmorepages" was set to true six times, and the routine was exited six times.  Still the output was four pages with one printing correctly, and three with two pages printed on one sheet.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  By the way, this is my first question, so be kind.

```
Private Sub PrintLines(Sender As Object, e As PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDoc.PrintPage
    Dim White As String = GetARGBString(PrinterDefaultBackcolor)
    Do Until Lines.Count = 0
        Dim Nextline As Lineformat = Lines.Dequeue
        If Nextline.NewPage Then
            e.HasMorePages = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
        With Nextline
            Dim LineBackColor As String = Nextline.backColor
            If LineBackColor <> White Or .Borders = True Then DrawShape(Nextline, e)
            If .Text <> "" Then DrawText(Nextline, e)
        End With
    Loop

End Sub

Private Sub DrawShape(Line As Lineformat, E As PrintPageEventArgs)
    With Line
        Dim Top As Integer = .Top * 100
        Dim Left As Integer = .Left * 100
        Dim Width As Integer = .BackGroundWidth * 100
        Dim Height As Integer = .BackGroundHeight * 100
        Dim Point As New Point(Left, Top)
        Dim Size As New Size(Width, Height)
        Dim Rect As New Rectangle(Point, Size)
        Dim TransparentFillColor As String = "00" & Strings.Right(.backColor, 6)
        Dim FillColor As FullColor = GetColorFromString(.backColor)
        Dim BorderPen As New Pen(Color.Black)
        Dim FillBrush As New SolidBrush(FillColor.Color)
        E.Graphics.FillRectangle(FillBrush, Rect)
        If Line.Borders = True Then
            E.Graphics.DrawRectangle(BorderPen, Rect)
        End If
    End With

End Sub
Private Sub DrawText(Line As Lineformat, E As PrintPageEventArgs)

    With Line
        Dim MyFont = SetFontStyle(.FontFamily, .FontPoints, .FontBold, .FontItalic, .FontUnderline)
        Dim TextColor As FullColor = GetColorFromString(.ForeColor)
        Dim MyBrush As New SolidBrush(TextColor.Color)
        Dim top As Integer = .Top * 100
        Dim Left As Integer = .Left * 100
        Dim Width As Integer = .LineWidth * 100
        Dim Height As Integer = .LineHeight * 100
        Dim point As New Point(Left, top)
        Dim Size As New Size(Width, Height)
        Dim Rect As New RectangleF(point, Size)
        Dim SF As New StringFormat()
        SF.FormatFlags = TextFormatFlags.WordEllipsis
        E.Graphics.DrawString(.Text, MyFont, MyBrush, Rect, SF)
    End With
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Silly question - this is for Microsoft Word, right?

Comment: You don't find issue in code simply by reading the code.  You need to debug it, i.e. set a breakpoint and then step through the code line by line.  You should have a clear idea of what you expect at each step so, as soon as what actually happens differs from your expectations, you've found an issue.  If reality never differs from your expectations then it's your expectations that are wrong.  If you find an issue and still can't fix it, at least you have more relevant information to post here.

Comment: I have stepped through the code, line by line.  I see it exits the routine six times with hasmorepages =true.  I have even put in dummy code to simplify the actions, simply printing the page number on an otherwise blank page.  it prints "page 7" on a separate page, but "page 5" overwrites "Page 6" , 3 over 4, and 1 over 2.  I have been trying to debug this for 2 days.  Is there something I don't understand about the process?  I no longer think it is my code, but how I interact with VB.net.

Comment: This is for Visual basic

Comment: Just another observation.  Why do two and only two pages overprint?  is that a clue to what is going wrong?

Comment: OK, I resolved the problem, by deleting and the reestablishing the printdocument subroutine with a different name.  Used the same code, but now everything works as expected.